# How do I fix Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, path

I am busy making a webapp and I want to be able to use firebase for authentication, however, I get an error with this line when importing it:

`import {db} from 'src/firebase/init.js'`

[This is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCJtf.png)

And this is my firebase init file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ******************,
  authDomain: ******************,
  databaseURL: ******************,
  projectId: ******************,
  storageBucket: ******************,
  messagingSenderId: ******************,
  appId: ******************,
  measurementId: ******************,
}

// init firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// init firestore service
const db = getFirestore(app)
export default db
```

I tried changing the path to the relative path, but that still didn't work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!